# Export members of distribution list and its nested groups

Tags: powershell, nested-lists, distribution-list

I am trying to create a powershell script that can **export the members of a DL to an excel file**. It should **also check for nested groups**, and it there are, list the members of that nested group in a new sheet named as that group. If it can also have the header as the nested group name, it will be good but is not ncessary.

Got a draft but its not working, obviously my reason for being here :)

can the pros please take a look and help me out?

```
$OutputFile = "DL-Members_$(Get-Date -Format ddMMMyyyy_hhmmss).xlsx"
$GroupName = "Test-DistributionList@contoso.com"

$Members = Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $GroupName -RecipientTypeDetails UserMailbox, MailUniversalDistributionGroup, DynamicDistributionGroup, SecurityDistributionGroup

$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()
$Sheet = $Workbook.Sheets.Item(1)
$Sheet.Name = "Distribution Group Members"
$Sheet.Cells.Item(1,1) = "Display Name"
$Sheet.Cells.Item(1,2) = "Primary Smtp Address"
$Sheet.Cells.Item(1,3) = "Recipient Type"

$Row = 2
foreach ($Member in $Members)
{
    $Sheet.Cells.Item($Row,1) = $Member.DisplayName
    $Sheet.Cells.Item($Row,2) = $Member.PrimarySmtpAddress
    $Sheet.Cells.Item($Row,3) = $Member.RecipientTypeDetails
    if ($Member.RecipientTypeDetails -eq "MailUniversalDistributionGroup" -or $Member.RecipientTypeDetails -eq "DynamicDistributionGroup" -or $Member.RecipientTypeDetails -eq "SecurityDistributionGroup")
    {
        $NestedMembers = Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $Member.PrimarySmtpAddress,RecipientTypeDetails UserMailbox, MailUniversalDistributionGroup, DynamicDistributionGroup, SecurityDistributionGroup
        $NestedSheet = $Workbook.Sheets.Add()
        $NestedSheet.Name = $Member.DisplayName
        $NestedSheet.Cells.Item(1,1) = "Display Name"
        $NestedSheet.Cells.Item(1,2) = "Primary Smtp Address"
        $NestedSheet.Cells.Item(1,3) = "Recipient Type"
        $NestedRow = 2
        foreach ($NestedMember in $NestedMembers)
        {
            $NestedSheet.Cells.Item($NestedRow,1) = $NestedMember.DisplayName
            $NestedSheet.Cells.Item($NestedRow,2) = $NestedMember.PrimarySmtpAddress
            $NestedSheet.Cells.Item($NestedRow,3) = $NestedMember.RecipientTypeDetails
            $NestedRow++
        }
    }
    $Row++
}

$Workbook.SaveAs($OutputFile)
$Excel.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel) | Out-Null

Write-Host "Members of distribution group '$GroupName' have been exported to $OutputFile" -foregroundcolor Green
```

Comment: "*not working*" in what aspect? Are you receiving an error, or is it just not giving you the results you're after? What isn't working for you?

Comment: getting an error-----------------Get-DistributionGroupMember : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'.
At C:\Scripts\TBT - 10feb - export_dl_&_nested_members-v2.ps1:24 char:26
+ ... edMembers = Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $Member.PrimarySmtp ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-DistributionGroupMember], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Get-DistributionGroupMember

Comment: First set you groups as an array so you can use contains : $groups = @(UserMailbox, MailUniversalDistributionGroup, DynamicDistributionGroup, SecurityDistributionGroup).  Then use Where-Object to filter the returns : Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $GroupName | Where-Object {$groups.Contains($_.RecipientTypeDetails) }.  The groups may need to be a string so use : $groups = @("UserMailbox", "MailUniversalDistributionGroup", 
"DynamicDistributionGroup", "SecurityDistributionGroup")

Comment: i may not have folllowed it correcty as i still get an error. i added the $groups... after the $groupname..... line and ended up with the following error. any chance you can make the change in the shown code and share?--------------------error--------------At C:\Scripts\ExO\TBT - 10feb - export_dl_&_nested_members-v2 - Copy.ps1:5 char:24
+ $groups = @(UserMailbox,MailUniversalDistributionGroup,DynamicDistrib ...
+                        ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument